# What is the bash command for redis-cli flushall?

Tags: php, laravel, bash, symfony, redis

I am using Symfony and Laravel framework for two different applications. Also, implemented redis. I want to write bash script to flush the cache data. I know redis command is redis-cli flushall.

However, I don't know how to write it in bash script? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

you create create redisflushall.sh after that you can put

```
redis-cli flushall
```

save and close for execute in terminal sh redisflushall.sh

Comment: There are few other commands as well.

`php artisan down
sudo supervisorctl stop all
redis-cli flushall
sudo supervisorctl start all`

Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

@Safak, I am using PHP's Laravel framework. In bash script I want to write some other commands along with redis command.

`php artisan down 
sudo supervisorctl stop all 
redis-cli flushall 
sudo supervisorctl start all
php artisan up`

Will this redis command work in this way?